# glassfish 3.1.2 admin console port 4848 closed

Tags: apache, console, glassfish, admin

I've got a remote server. There is glassfish 3.1.2 running behind apache 2.2. The administration port 4848 is closed so that I cannot use http://some_server.com:4848 where some_server is the domain name of my server. How can I configure apache and glassfish in order to be able to access glassfish administration console?

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by closed? It is blocked by a firewall? Do you want to open the firewall or to have Apache acting as a proxy?

Comment: Yes, the port 4848 is blocked by firewall. I want apache to act as a proxy. I've heard about using mod_proxy, mod_jk or mod_proxy_ajp, but I couldn't find proper explanation of how to use them in order give access to glassfish administration console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only guess, that you are trying to do something that is called "port forwarding".
You can use apache httpd mod_proxy for that:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html

To give you a first idea about how this could look like:

```
<Location /adminconsole/>
ProxyPass http://your.glassfish-server:4848/
</Location>
```

that would make your admin-console available through your apache:8080/adminconsole

Note: I highly recommend not to do so. There are good reasons why network admins tend to block everything beside 80/8080/443. So you might talk with them about a good solution for your problem.

Comment: Agreed with the note. The network admins will likely suggest allowing access to the full port range only from inside a corporate network or VPN. This is hopefully already the case for SSH connections so extending those rules to more ports would be the easiest solution.